# Cannot transfer files to iPhone with libimobiledevice

Tags: 18.04, vlc, iphone

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and am not able transfer files from my PC to my iPhone using libimobiledevice. Any file I attempt to transfer to my iPhone gets stuck at 0 bytes / X bytes - approximately 596,523 hours le.........

I've tried with different files of varying sizes and none of them work. I've had similar issues with USB file transfer, but usually after waiting the transfer will eventually complete. The application I am attempting to transfer to is VLC. I'm aware that there is a WiFi sharing option within VLC and have been using that in the meantime.